# Facing 503 error while uploading bulk product

Tags: magento-1.9, server-setup

I am facing issue while trying to upload bulk amount of product to my magento site.
I have 1M product in a csv format, but I split the file in several csv files including 10k data in each file.
But when I am trying to import the file after a while shows 503 server unavailable error. 
After trying several times I split the files into more smaller pieces where only 500 rows available. But still facing the same issue.

Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: if you dont find any solution, just go for magmi, hope that will work.....

Answer (score 1):

1. Find **maintenance.flag** file in your magento root directory.
2. Remove **maintenance.flag** file.